# I would like the output of a query to be prefix by an hyphen

Tags: sql

I created the view below. I would like the output of employee name(that is called name in my statement) to be prefix by an hyphen. I am trying to
write an SQL tree structure using oracle. Thanks for your help

```
create or replace view connected_employee 
as
select lpad(' ', (level - 1) * 3) ||  name as name, title, position, officekey
from employee
connect by prior employeekey=managerkey
start with employeekey=501;
```

Comment: ||'-'|| is more enough right?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing either double quotes or square brackets around the view name.